# Select Only the Most Recent Row

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, oracle12c

I'm using a query to pull the valuation cost of projects. It works well, except sometimes it returns multiple rows for a valuation.

How can I modify my query to get only the most recent record to avoid multiple rows?

### Query

```
SELECT
    to_char( BVALUATN.G3_CALC_VALUE, '$999,999,999,999,999' ) AS "Valuation",
    TO_CHAR( G6ACTION.G6_ACT_DD, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS "Final Date"

FROM PERMIT

LEFT OUTER JOIN G6ACTION G6ACTION
    ON  (PERMIT.B1_PER_ID1 = G6ACTION.B1_PER_ID1)
    AND (PERMIT.B1_PER_ID3 = G6ACTION.B1_PER_ID3)

LEFT OUTER JOIN BVALUATN BVALUATN ON (PERMIT.B1_PER_ID1 = BVALUATN.B1_PER_ID1 AND PERMIT.B1_PER_ID3 = BVALUATN.B1_PER_ID3)

WHERE TRUNC (G6ACTION.G6_ACT_DD) > TO_DATE ('01/01/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
AND TRUNC (G6ACTION.G6_ACT_DD) < TO_DATE ('04/06/2022', 'mm/dd/yyyy')

ORDER BY "Valuation" DESC;
```

### Output

[image]

### Desired Output

[image]

I'm interested in seeing various suggestions to see what works best for different use-cases, e.g., using an aggregate function, subquery, etc. Thanks for any help.

I am using Oracle Database version 12.1.0.2.0.

Comment: It sounds like you want the last row per valuation, and not just the most recent row overall. Is that right?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a group by on the valuation and select the max date like below

```
SELECT
    to_char( BVALUATN.G3_CALC_VALUE, '$999,999,999,999,999' ) AS "Valuation",
    MAX(TO_CHAR( G6ACTION.G6_ACT_DD, 'mm/dd/yyyy')) AS "Final Date"

FROM B1PERMIT

LEFT OUTER JOIN G6ACTION G6ACTION
    ON  (PERMIT.B1_PER_ID1 = G6ACTION.B1_PER_ID1)
    AND (PERMIT.B1_PER_ID3 = G6ACTION.B1_PER_ID3)

LEFT OUTER JOIN BVALUATN BVALUATN ON (PERMIT.B1_PER_ID1 = BVALUATN.B1_PER_ID1 AND PERMIT.B1_PER_ID3 = BVALUATN.B1_PER_ID3)

WHERE TRUNC (G6ACTION.G6_ACT_DD) > TO_DATE ('01/01/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
AND TRUNC (G6ACTION.G6_ACT_DD) < TO_DATE ('04/06/2022', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
GROUP BY to_char( BVALUATN.G3_CALC_VALUE, '$999,999,999,999,999' )
ORDER BY "Valuation" DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using DB version `12c+`, then you can use `FETCH` clause following `ORDER BY` for ascending `"Valuation"` such as

```sql
ORDER BY "Valuation", "Final Date" DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

If you needed both of the equal values, then you'd replace `ONLY` with `WITH TIES` and remove the part `, "Final Date" DESC`

Comment: Looking for last row per valuation, not just the most recent row overall.

Comment: Well, can you express what's the difference between the last row and the most recent row overall, since it's hard to distinguish considering the current dataset @GTSJoe